# ASP.NET MVC throws exception when binding to Dictionary with key of type int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, dictionary

One of my model properties is:

`public Dictionary<int, bool> SelectedAuthors { get; set; }`

When I try to bind response data to model, it throws `KeyNotFoundException`.

My helper looks like:

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SelectedAuthors[a.AuthorId])`

and source code in browser seems to be ok:

`<input checked="checked" id="SelectedAuthors_29_" name="SelectedAuthors[29]" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="SelectedAuthors[29]" type="hidden" value="false" />`

It throws the same exception with `int?`, but **works fine with `string` indexes**, so If I will not find solution, I will have to convert values to `string`. Could there be something wrong with my code or it never works with `int`?

Comment: It's a class with `int AuthorId { get; set; }` property.

Comment: MVC has never played very well with dictionaries and in order to bind to your model, you need inputs `<input type="hidden" name="SelectedAuthors[0].Key" value="29" />` and `<input type="checkbox" name="SelectedAuthors[0].Value" value="true" /><input name="SelectedAuthors[0].Value" type="hidden" value="false" />` While its possible, it will be far easier to use a view model(s) with simple `List<T>`